# jQuery .select() Failed To Copy Text Into Clipboard

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
  function copyMyID() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var copyText = $("#myref").text();
    alert(copyText);
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
```

I want to copy `copyText` variable into clipboard. It works until `alert`, but `.select()` and `.execCommand` doesn't work.

What did I missed here? thank you.

Comment: A string does have a `select` method. There should be an error in your console about that. You can call it on the jQuery reference `$("#myref").select()`. See https://api.jquery.com/select/

Comment: @HereticMonkey typo?

Comment: what typo? I don't see any typo on my code

Comment: As (mostly) noted above, `string.select()` does **not exist** so there will be an error in your console - *always check the console for errors*.  `$().select()` will trigger select, which isn't what you want here - you need `$("#myref")[0].select()` to select the text in the input, you'll also want `$("#myref")[0].focus()` as detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67179128/jquery-select-failed-to-copy-text-into-clipboard

Comment: @SaintRobson the "@" indicates the comment is direct towards HereticMonkey - "a string does have a select method" should be "a string does not have a select method"

Comment: @freedomn-m got what I meant to say :).